# How to Clone a DocumentDB Document?

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a utility in C# that updates the value of the `id` field in a Cosmos DB document.

To do so, my plan-of-attack is:

- Read the existing document from the database as a generic `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document`
- Clone the existing document into a new document
- Update the `id` in the new document to my liking
- Create the new document in the database
- Delete the old document

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to clone a `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document`.  My existing code is clearly just creating a copy:

```cs
var existingDocument = new Document(); // Pretend this is coming from database and is an actual document.
var newDocument = existingDocument; // Need to clone object... how?
newDocument.Id = $"{docType}_{docId}";
newDocument.SetPropertyValue("_rid", null);
newDocument.SetPropertyValue("_self", null);
newDocument.SetPropertyValue("_etag", null);
newDocument.SetPropertyValue("_attachments", null);
newDocument.SetPropertyValue("_ts", null);
```

How can I create a clone of the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document` so that the `newDocument` isn't simply a reference to the `existingDocument`?

Answer (score 1):

My "plan of attack" was wrong... there's no need for me to try and clone the `Document` object in order to update the `id` field.  I can simply use the `ReplaceDocumentAsync()` method on the `DocumentClient`.  Duh.

```cs
await _docClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(existingDocument, options);
```